# Better way to apply formula to specific column of inputfile, and pass-through all other columns as-is

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I regularly need to apply simple formulas to input data give in textual tabular form.

In the beginning, I wrote specific little functions for each use-case. Then I re-factored the "common code" into a bash function. This works well, but feels suboptimal.

*Here's my "old solution", walking through all fields, checking/reacting:*

```
calcc(){
  awkcmd='{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (i==col) printf "%s ",'
  awkcmd+="$2"
  awkcmd+='; else printf "%s ", $i ;}; print "";}'
  awk -v col=$1 "$awkcmd" | column -t
}
```

*Contrived usage example:*

"Replace groupName (Column4) in `ls -l`-output with the square of the dayNumber (Column7)"

`$ ls -l | calcc 4 '$7*$7'`

Is there a better way, or a (POSIX) tool that has so-far escaped my research?

EDIT: @RalphRönnquist pointed out, that `$1..$n` are writable, and so could propose a much shorter version. Since `print` is the default `awk` action, this can be shortened even more. ==>

```
$ calcc() { awk "\$$1=$2" | column -t; }
$ calcc-nc() { awk "\$999=$1" | column -t; }
```

The second function adds a *n*ew *c*olumn to the end with the calculation result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` is good for this, but you could do it simpler, with

```
calcc() {
    awk "{\$$1=$2;print}" | column -t
}
```

Whether that's better or not is your choice.

Comment: Ooh, nice. I did not know, that $1..$n were r/w. Thank you for furthering my grok of awk (+1). Yes, I consider this better. And this version can also add columns by specifying `$1` to be larger than `NF`. This now has a home in my bashrc.

Comment: @AlexStragies Unrelated to your question: assigning to `$i` or to `NF` is a very useful technique.  It triggers re-calculation of `$0`, which is useful by itself.  F.i. try this: `echo 1/2/3 | awk -v FS=/ -v OFS=: '{NF=NF} 1'`